# Assign specific colours to specific values in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors, tidyverse

I have a rather simple issue in ggplot2 I am not being able to solve.

I have the following dataframe:

```
date country party         value
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>         <dbl>
  2019 UK      Conservatives    15
  2019 UK      Labour           16
  2019 UK      Lib Dem          12
  2019 UK      Greens           31
  2020 UK      Conservatives    13
  2020 UK      Labour           14
  2020 UK      Lib Dem          12
  2020 UK      Greens           32
```

And I want to plot but assign specific colours to different values of `party`.
I've tried it this way:

```
p <- df%>%
ggplot( aes(x=as.factor(date), y=value, fill=party)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
  geom_text(aes(label=value), vjust=1.6, color="white",
            position = position_dodge(0.9), size=3.5)+
  theme_minimal()
```

and then:

```
p +   scale_colour_manual(values = c("Conservatives" = "cyan",
                                 "Greens" = "chartreuse3",
                                 "Labour" = "brown3",
                                 "Lib Dems" = "darkgoldenrod1")) #these are the colours I want to assign each level of `party`.
```

[image: Plot I get out]

But as you can see instead of actually printing out the colours I select, I still get the same colours as if I just called `p`.

Any idea why?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `scale_fill_manual` instead of `scale_colour_manual`:

```
p + scale_fill_manual(values = c("cyan", "chartreuse3", "brown3", "darkgoldenrod1"))
```